# file_get_contents doesn't work with path and variable

Tags: php, path, file-get-contents

This works:

```
if(isset($_POST["forms"])) {
$form=$_POST["forms"];
$content = file_get_contents($form);
}
```

My file's name is $form and is chosen through a "select" form.

But those files (or else those options of the select form) are located in a folder !

And for some reason... this below doesn't work !

```
$content = file_get_contents('forms/', $form);
```

The command file_get_contents states very clearly that the 1st operand is the path.

So I've tried

```
$content = file_get_contents("forms/", $form);
$content = file_get_contents('forms', $form);
$content = file_get_contents('forms' $form);
```

And many other stupid attempts. But at the end it seems that PATH + variable don't go along! Is that true ? It can't be.

Comment: If you want to concatenate two strings, use `.`, not `,`.

Comment: @Sammitch Is a contention really necessary?? Why not  `("forms/$form")`

Comment: I recommend of using `$form = basename($_POST["forms"]);` to protect against path traversal vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

RE: "And for some reason... this below doesn't work !"
$content = file_get_contents('forms/', $form);

And it never will.  Loose the comma.

It is very likely that your `file_get_contents('forms/', $form);` does not work because `file_get_contents()` has only one parameter (no comma), the file name.

Not sure but maybe try

```
$content = file_get_contents("forms/$form");
```

Or more likely

```
file_get_contents("./forms/$form");
```

Comment: thanks man worked with  $content = file_get_contents("./forms/$form");

Comment: Glad it works.  Don't forget to give my answer the check mark.